# my plot is not beginning from the origin how to fix it

Tags: python

My code below is working properly but I have an issue in the final plot where my schematic is not beginning from the common origin, but instead it is starting from (0,0) but as a point not as the common origin. How to fix it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, cuda
@jit(target="cuda")
def func2(a):
        for i in range(10000000):
                a[i] += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
        n = 10000000
        a = np.ones(n, dtype=np.float64)
        b = np.ones(n, dtype=np.float32)
r3=np.arange(1.1,10,0.1)
r1=1
r2=1.1
h=20
kconcrete=1.4
kins=5
R1cond=(1/(4*np.pi*kconcrete))*((1/r1)-(1/r2))
R2cond=(1/(4*np.pi*kins))*((r3-r2)/r2)
Rconv=1/(h*4*np.pi*r3**2)
Rtotal=R1cond+R2cond+Rconv
Rtotal=R1cond+R2cond+Rconv
plt.plot(r3-r2,R2cond,label="resistance of the insulation",color="orange")
plt.plot(r3-r2,Rconv,label="resistance of the convection",color="green")
plt.axhline(R1cond,label="resistance of the concrete",color="yellow")
plt.plot(r3-r2,Rtotal,label="total resistance",color="purple")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the X and Y limits of the plot with:

```
plt.xlim((0,100))
plt.ylim((0,100))
```

Before the `plt.show()`